# Is it possible to dowload a Windows AMI created in EC2 for a local copy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am making a backup of all the instances in EC2 and I am following the best practices specified by techsoup for backup

In this it is mentioned to keep a local copy of the server at 2 different locations. I was wondering if it is possible to download a Windows AMI created in Amazon EC2 which was not exported from the local VM or using the AWS CLI. It is completely an EC2 instance whose AMI was created for backup.

Can I keep a local copy of the AMI for on-premise backup?

Comment: Keeping in backup of ami on amazon is way more reliable than your premise setup. I dont get it why you want to back you amis on your side?

Comment: Can you share a link to the Techsoup article?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. If the AMI needs to be kept in two locations then those locations should be separate AWS regions. You can copy the AMI to another region using the AWS CLI's [copy-image](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/copy-image.html) or via the AWS console.

Comment: Thank you. And I think a workaround to store ec2 instance in a different service provider can be achieved using cloudendure. I am not sure if my approach is correct yet. If you have any input on this it will help me a lot

Comment: I'm not familiar with CloudEndure but you may find the AWS whitepaper on AWS Disaster Recovery useful: http://media.amazonwebservices.com/AWS_Disaster_Recovery.pdf